# Using djoser in DRF When signing up, I want to add my Username to the form along with my email address and password

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I'm using djoser at DRF.
When signing up, I want to add Username to the form along with my email address and password.
https://djoser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Below is the DRF user signup screen
Is it possible to add a UserName form here?
I couldn't find a way to do it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ysgDX.png)

**Views.py**

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (permissions.UpdateOwnProfile,)
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

**Urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
    path('api/auth/',include('djoser.urls')), #add
    path('api/auth/',include('djoser.urls.jwt')), #add
    path('api/auth/users/',include('djoser.urls')), #add
]
```

**Serializer.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password = serializers.CharField(write_only=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'password', 'state', 'city', 'address', 'zipcode', 'phone_number')
    def create(self,validated_data):
            user = User.objects.create_user(
                email=validated_data['email'],
                username=validated_data['username'],
                password=validated_data['password'],
            )
```

I tried to add Username to the form along with my email address and password.

Comment: why did you set permission class on the signup ViewSet?

Comment: UpdateOwnProfile is a custom permission I am applying in my UserView. UpdateOwnProfile restricts users to only update their own profile.

Comment: i think you have to make a separate API to for profile update, and provide those fields that user can update.